# tee displays output in incorrect order in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a bash script for a university assignment where multiple operations need to be performed for a certain directory (given to the script as an argument).

1. Display all files/directories with certain permissions (permissions are given as an argument in octal format)
2. Display files in directory tree that were modified within the last x days (x is an argument)
3. Display subdirectories of tree that were accessed within the last x days (x is the same argument used above)
4. Display all pipe/socket type files in directory
5. Display all empty files within the directory (NOT in any subdirectories)

At the end of every operation, the script should also display the number of files (or subdirectories) found.

I'm using this command to print the desired output *(e.g. operation 1)*: `echo "$files_perms" | tee >(echo "Files found: $(wc -l)")`

**The issue is that `tee`'s output is not being displayed at the correct order for operations after the first and second.**

1st operation (output is normal):

[image]

2nd operation (output is still normal):

[image]

3rd, 4th & 5th operations (output order is messed up - arrows signify `tee`'s output from each operation and op3-op5 is the actual output of each operation):

[image]

Here is the code for each function:

```bash
#display files in the current directory tree with the specified permissions
sub1 () {
    files_perms=$(ls $1 -l | grep $2 --color=never)
    echo "$files_perms" | tee >(echo "Files found: $(wc -l)")
    echo ""
}

#display files in the current directory tree that were modified within the last $2 days (without hidden files)
sub2 () {
    files_modlastxdays=$(find $1 -not -path '*/.*' -type f -mtime -$2)
    echo "$files_modlastxdays" | tee >(echo "Files found: $(wc -l)")
    echo ""
}

#display subdirectories in the current directory tree that were accessed within the last $2 days (without hidden subdirs)
sub3 () {
    subdirs_acclastxdays=$(find $1 -not -path '*/.*' -type d -atime -$2)
    echo "$subdirs_acclastxdays" | tee >(echo "Subdirectories found: $(wc -l)")
    echo ""
}

#display all files that are of pipe/socket type in the current directory tree
sub4 () {
    ps_files=$(find $1 \( -type p -o -type s \))
    echo "$ps_files" | tee >(echo "Files found: $(wc -l)")
    echo ""
}

#display all empty files in current directory (NOT in subdirectories)
sub5 () {
    empty_files=$(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty)
    echo "$empty_files" | tee >(echo "Files found: $(wc -l)")
    echo ""
}
```

The functions are called as follows:

```bash
echo "Files with permission $1 ($rwx_converted):"
sub1 $3 $rwx_converted

echo "Files that were modified within the last $2 days:"
sub2 $3 $2

echo "Subdirectories that were accessed within the last $2 days:"
sub3 $3 $2

echo "Files that are of pipe/socket type:"
sub4 $3

echo "Empty files (NOT in subdirectories):"
sub5 $3
```

`$1` is the file permissions argument in octal format (`rwx_converted` is the octal format converted to rwx format),

`$2` is the x days argument for operations 2 & 3,

and `$3` is the directory argument used for the `ls`/`find` commands.

Example execution of the script: `bash labscript2.sh 755 8 /home/na-no`

Why is `tee`'s output not being displayed in the correct order (at the end of every `ls`/`find` command and **not** after a bunch of lines)?

Comment: FYI the data can easily be output in the correct order _without_ tee _or_ process substitution, but you didn't ask that. (And since you are new and may not know, materially changing the question after it's been answered is considered abusive and could get you banned.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple concurrent processes running simultaneously. Output order will depend on which process writes first.

For example, it appears your fourth `tee` has started writing output while the third `wc` is still processing its input.

Consider:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 | tee >(sleep 8; echo 1b) >(sleep 4; echo 1c)
echo 2 | tee >(sleep 2; echo 2b) >(sleep 6; echo 2c)
echo 3 | tee >(         echo 3b) >(         echo 3c)

echo done
```

Note that `tee` exits once it has finished copying its input to all its outputs. However the processes started by bash's process substitution `>(...)` run asynchronously and may still be running after `tee` (or even the script itself) has exited.

Note also, that it is not defined which of `tee`'s outputs is written first. If all outputs are actually the same file, it will be even more likely that outputs are intermingled. For example, on my machine, the third `tee` line above outputs:

```
3b
3c
3
```

i.e. It seems that the `stdout` of `tee` is written after the other outputs, which means there is no guarantee that you will get your `wc` output in the order you expect.

Comment: How do I avoid process substitution then? By appending a `sleep` command before the output just as you showed above or by using a different method?

Comment: Since you are storing the output, you can just elide the tee. eg.  `lines=$(find ...); echo "$lines"; echo "Lines output: $(wc -l <<<"$lines")"`

Comment: It works now, thank you!